# Pattern matching in conjunciton with filter

Tags: scala

given the following code that I#d like to refactor - Im only interested in lines matching the 1st pattern that occurs, is there a way of shortening this like lets say to use it in conjunction with filter?

With best regards,

Stefan

```
def processsHybridLinks(it: Iterator[String]): Unit =
    {
     for (line <- it) {
        val lineSplit = lineSplitAndFilter(line)
        lineSplit match {
          case Array(TaggedString(origin), TaggedString(linkName), TaggedString(target), ".") =>
            {
              println("trying to find pages " + origin + " and " + target)
              val originPageOpt = Page.findOne(MongoDBObject("name" -> (decodeUrl(origin))))
              val targetPageOpt = Page.findOne(MongoDBObject("name" -> (decodeUrl(target))))
              (originPageOpt, targetPageOpt) match {
                case (Some(origin), Some(target)) =>
                  createHybridLink(origin, linkName, target)
                  Logger.info(" creating Hybrid Link")
                case _ => Logger.info(" couldnt create Hybrid LInk")
              }

            }
          case _ =>
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `collect` method. It allows you to use a `PartialFunction[A,B]` defined using an incomplete pattern match as a sort of combination `map` and `filter`:

```
it.map(lineSplitAndFilter) collect {
  case Array(TaggedString(o), TaggedString(n), TaggedString(t), ".") =>
    (n, Page.findOne(...), Page.findOne(...))
} foreach {
  case (n, Some(o), Some(t)) => ...
  case _ =>
}
```